# Non-parametric estimate of conditional expectation

Tags: nonparametric, conditional-expectation, nonparametric-bayes, joint-distribution

I have a (fairly smooth) function $f$ and a sample $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1,\ldots,N}$ from the joint
distribution of the random variables $X$ and $Y$.  I would like to estimate the conditional
expectation function $g(y) = E(f(X) \;|\; Y=y)$ non-parametrically.

The random variables $X$ and $Y$ are either two or three dimensional, which makes me hesitant to
estimate their joint density in order to plug in for the conditional expectation.  My first guess
is to use a formula like 
\begin{equation}
    \widehat{g}(y) = \frac{\sum_i f(x_i) K(y-y_i)}{\sum_i K(y-y_i)},
\end{equation}
where $K$ is a kernel function suitable for density estimation.  Is this a reasonable estimator?  Is
there a more suitable estimator that I should use?

Dirichlet process mixtures quite successfully model the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$.  It
would be great if this method extends easily to estimating the conditional expectation.

If it helps, the function $f$ is bounded from below.    In my application, the dependence
between $X$ and $Y$ is fairly weak, but I am only interested in g(y) up to an additive constant.  The final quantity that I need for my work is the sum of g(y) for many different random variables $X$.

Thank you.

Comment: Afterwards, I noticed that the problem is much easier if I define $Z = f(X)$ so that the (Z,Y) distribution has only one more dimension than $Y$.  Then, at least for gaussian kernels (and others that satisfy a few conditions), the formula I provide for $\widehat{g}(y)$ is equal to the plug in estimator from the kernel density estimate of the joint density of (Z,Y).  This probably solves my problem unless someone has a better idea.

Comment: Did you try this paper? https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ejs/1458655725

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I didn’t try that paper as it looks like it was written a couple of years after my question!  I think their bias corrected estimate has higher variance, so the pseudo-KDE formula I have still looks attractive.